# What does "hemicontinuity" of a multi-valued "function" mean intuitively?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, analysis

I am wondering about this. I saw this on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function

> One can differentiate many continuity concepts, primarily closed graph property and upper and lower hemicontinuity. (One should be warned that often the terms upper and lower semicontinuous are used instead of upper and lower hemicontinuous reserved for the case of weak topology in domain; yet we arrive at the collision with the reserved names for upper and lower semicontinuous real-valued function). There exist also various definitions for measurability of multifunction.

But what does this mean, this "upper and lower hemicontinuity" and "closed graph property" mean *intuitively*? The page on that (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity) doesn't seem to be quite as helpful as I'd like since it's in very general topological terms.

The most familiar type of multivalued "function" (relation) I'm aware of is the ones involving complex numbers, but I presume all these arising from analytic continuations are simply *continuous* once maximally extended (thus presumably both upper and lower hemicontinuous)? I'm also familiar with "semicontinuity" of a real valued ordinary function (left and right continuity) -- is that what is being referred to here or something else? Is there a relationship? If we took a complex multivalued function, say, what would we have to do to it to make it only, say, upper hemicontinuous but not lower? What would such a thing "look" like? If we "tear" one of the sheets, would that do the job (leaving it still defined everywhere but we cut and bent one so that an 'edge' of discontinuity exists with continuity from one direction yet it still covers the plane. Obviously this breaks holomorphizm as well as continuity even outside the tear zone if we allow arbitrary deformation like this but we're not after that when we're dealing with a more basic geometric/topological property such as this)? That is, does the hemicontinuity of multi-valued map just generalization of the usual idea of continuity from one direction but not another to a multi-valued setting, or what? (It seems like maybe, but maybe not. What if we tear several sheets but they are one-sided continuous from different directions?) I'd be curious as to how this relates to this more familiar concept of the complex multivalued relation.